# Как сделать динамическое обновление содержимого страницы?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть кнопка, которая добавляет строку в таблицу. Отправляется ajax-запрос на добавление записи в БД.
Есть такое решение:

```
function reloadPage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'orders/reloadPage',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'test':'yes'},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#displayAutoReload').html(data);
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

Но при выполнении этой функции дублируется подключение js файла и при последующих нажатиях на кнопку добавления строки функция будет выполняться 2-3-6-8раз.

Comment: Как выглядит элемент с id ```displayAutoReload``` и что конкретно возвращается после ajax-запроса?

Comment: Скорее всего ты на сервере возвращаешь весь контент сайта, а нужно возвращать только конкретный результат